# Package with bad signature got instlaled on second try: how?

Tags: apt, security, gnupg

I executed my daily `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` command, and got a bad signature error when hitting google chrome:

```
Fetched 2178 kB in 2s (981 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A040830F7FAC5991 Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  google-chrome-stable
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] N
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

After searching Ask Ubuntu, I found this question, which told me to execute `apt-key update`. Did that and the result:

```
[Gx1sptDTDa] $ sudo apt-key update
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key FBB75451: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key EFE21092: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:              unchanged: 4
```

So, this seems to me like nothing got updated; no new keys, right?

So, then why, does apt not complain on the following try:

```
[Gx1sptDTDa] $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1210 B]                  
Fetched 1408 B in 1s (758 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-host dkms dnsutils gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  gir1.2-webkit-3.0 google-chrome-stable libbind9-90 libdns100 libgail-3-0
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90
  libjasper1 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblwres90 libplymouth2 libsepol1 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common lightdm
  plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text xserver-common xserver-xorg-core
  34 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Need to get 71,4 MB of archives.
  After this operation, 2910 kB disk space will be freed.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

Seems like it did download some new stuff from the google keyserver and sure enough it installed. So my question: what exactly did `apt-key update` do?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-key update` did not do anything. `apt-get update` did. Note these lines:

```
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1210 B]
```

`apt` has found updated package information, and this information now matched the new version of `google-chrome-stable`. How `apt` downloaded the new package without having `update` run has always been a mystery to me.

Comment: but i _did_  run `sudo apt-get update` just two minutes earlier! And then it did give me the signature error.

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa I suppose you had spectacularly bad timing. Otherwise you should have got `Hit`s on the Google repositories, instead of `Get`s. `Get`s only happen if the remote file changed.

Comment: I know that, hence my question (I in fact left out all "hits" from all the other (non-google) repositories). It just occurs to me that this is all very coincidental. Like some google employee noticed the problem within the two minutes I looked on Ask Ubuntu, executed `apt-key update` and tried installing again.

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa I doubt any *correction* was done on the server side. I have seen it happen many times, that `apt-get install` or `upgrade` seems to download a newer version of the package than it is supposed to be aware of, and gives the authentication error, immediately fixed by an `update`. That is the mystery here.

Comment: That's just........ weird.